# Is there any way to see my minor and major contributions as a list in documentation?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, documentation, documentation-editor

As in documentation beta, contributors are divided in two categories named major and minor. It is painful to go to each of my contributed examples/topics to see whether my contribution is major or minor.

So, I am asking here: Is there any way to see the list of examples/topics where I am a minor/major contributor?

Comment: This may be more of a feature request than a discussion but I think it's a good feature request

Comment: There is [this tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3555000/manetsus?tab=documentation&sort=contributions), but it doesn't break out contributions into major and minor. (Not yet, at least.)

Comment: @JonEricson I am aware of that tab. But there is no detailed information like how many changes, how many character changed etc. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The contributors tab on your profile now list major and minor contributions*.

[image]

As part of this change, the proposed changes tab lists *all* changes (approved, rejected, or still pending review).

<sub>* Note that there is currently a bug where deleted topics and examples still show up on that tab.  It's not exactly *wrong* (you'd be a contributor again if they were undeleted), but it'll be fixed in the next deploy or two.</sub>